# Reset or clear a input type file field

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I use a upload form / group in my page. This works well. But it is not possible to add a reset/clear function to this. my control is:

```
          <div id="uploadform" style="width:100%;" data-provides="fileupload">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <label class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-folder-plus"></i></label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="custom-file" >
                    <input type="file" name="sampleFile" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01">
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
                  </div>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                     <button type="button" id="fileupload" class="btn btn-primary">Upload!</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

          </div>
```

I have a function to detect on change events

```
    $('#inputGroupFile01').on('change',function(e){
        console.log("onchange");
        //get the file name
        var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
        //replace the "Choose a file" label
        $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(fileName);
    });
```

The file selection and the label are all ok, but it is impossible to reset the input file.
The change event is never fired.  I moved the reset to the upload button

```
    $( '#fileupload' ).click(function() {
        console.log("Upload");
        $('#inputGroupFile01').val('');
        return;
```

But also no effect. I also tried to use all inside a form tag and to call this.form.reset(). No effect. Iam really confused. I think the change event is never fired because the input typ="file" is never cleared / resented? Any idea?

Additional Info:
If I add a file to the control. Change event is fired. In all other cases the change event is not fired. Not with `$('#inputGroupFile01').val('');` nor with `this.form.reset();`

Comment: if you have a form in your HTML just add reset button, plain simple tag without javascript or jQuery, [Reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset)

Comment: @Ma'mounothman Comment from the linked page: *You should usually avoid including reset buttons in your forms. They're rarely useful, and are instead more likely to frustrate users who click them by mistake (often while trying to click the submit button).*

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're missing something in the question, the change event does seem to fire

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava, good note, thank you, on the other hand the functionality is there, so it's our job as developers to use the reset() programmatically then, better that looping/selecting all elements.

Comment: If I click on the fileuload button, the change event is not fired. Console said not.

Comment: As I wrote. this.form.reset(); also do not fire the change event.

Comment: What do you see in the console? Any errors?

Comment: Nothing. Just the Upload message from Upload button.

Comment: BTW: If I add a file to the input file, the change event is fired.

Comment: @ingo, I just want to ask if you have a `<form>` tag in your HTML?

Comment: "*If I add a file to the control the Change event is fired. In all other cases the change event is not fired.*" - UI events only fire from UI actions.  Calling `.val()` is not a UI action so doesn't raise an event.  You can do `$("#id").val('').change()` to fire the event if/when you need it from code.

Comment: `$("#id").val('')` works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/je7xnwqL/  is the issue that your "onchange" event is not firing when you clear it this way?  If so, it won't (see comment above).

Comment: @freedomn-m, you made my day. Append the change() will solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet will help you

```js
$("#clear").click(function() {  
  $("#inputGroupFile01").val('');
  console.log("clear field", $("#inputGroupFile01").val())
})
$("#fileupload").click(function() {
  console.log("current url is", $("#inputGroupFile01").val())
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <div id="uploadform" style="width:100%;" data-provides="fileupload">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <label class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-folder-plus"></i></label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-file" >
                    <input type="file" name="sampleFile"  class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01">
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                     <button type="button" id="fileupload" class="btn btn-primary">Upload!</button>
                      <button type="button" id="clear" class="btn btn-primary">Clear!</button>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You mean the code snippet from my jsfiddle???  Wow.  Bit rude to copy someone else's code/example and not give them credit!  And it doesn't help at all as that's not OPs issue!

Comment: something bit different dear

Answer (score 1):

> If I add a file to the control the Change event is fired. In all other cases the change event is not fired

and

> it is impossible to reset the input file. The change event is never fired

The issue here is that UI events (click, change) only fire from UI actions (the user clicking or making a change to the control)

Code actions such as calling `.val()` is not a UI action so doesn't raise an event.

You can raise/trigger an event via code if/when you need one, eg

```
$("#id").val('').change()
```

---

In this specific case, OPs `.val('')` *is* working, but they have it hidden behind a UX wrapper so cannot see the `input type=file` changing instead relying on the change event to update the wrapper.  As the change event doesn't fire from `.val('')` the wrapper is not being updated so it gives the appearance of not updating.